# sinon - check if returned response object matches desired object

Tags: node.js, sinon, chai

I'm using sinon spy in order to spy on HTTP response status and send.
The object I return in 'send' in json like so:

```
{
message: 'bla bla',
fields: { request_id ='000', user_id = '3434324' } 
}
```

How can I checks if the returned response includes such an object, structure and values.

Here's my code:

```
var responseStatusSpy = sandbox.spy(res, 'status');
var responseSendSpy = sandbox.spy(res, 'send');
var response_object = {message: "invalid request - no merchant id", fields: {'request_id':'0000', 'user_id' = '2323223'}};

merchantController.getList(req, res);
responseSendSpy.withArgs ?????
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sinon.assert.calledExactlyWith(responseSendSpy, response_object )`. Check the `assert` section of the documentation :)

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin, I'm getting an error "sinon.assert.calledExactlyWith"

Comment: Check the reference for those methods, I might have misspelled it

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing a working example using an Express controller, since your code was broken in some parts.  Don't worry about the dependencies - the principles are the same no matter what framework you're using.

### controller.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/example', function(req, res) {

  res.send({
    message: 'bla bla',
    fields: {
      request_id: '000',
      user_id: '3434324'
    }
  });


});


module.exports = router;
```

### test.js

```
'use strict';

const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const SinonChai = require('sinon-chai');

var sinonStubPromise = require('sinon-stub-promise');
sinonStubPromise(sinon);
require('sinon-mongoose');

chai.use(SinonChai);
chai.should();

const mockHttp = require('node-mocks-http');

const controller = require('./controller');


context('Test', () => {


  beforeEach(() => {
    if (!this.sandbox) {
      this.sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
    } else {
      this.sandbox.restore();
    }
  });


  it('should pass the test',
    (done) => {

      // Mocking req and res with node-mocks-http
      let req = mockHttp.createRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/example'
      });

      let res = mockHttp.createResponse({
        eventEmitter: require('events').EventEmitter
      });

      // spy on the response status
      this.sandbox.spy(res, 'send');

      var response_object = {
        message: 'bla bla',
        fields: {
          request_id: '000',
          user_id: '3434324'
        }
      };

      res.on('end', function() {
        try {
          res.send.should.have.been.calledWith(response_object);
          done();
        } catch (e) {
          done(e);
        }
      });

      controller.handle(req, res);

    });

});
```

First use a 3rd party HTTP req / res mocking library to create a valid request and response object.  Next set a spy on the `send()` method of the response and attach an event listener to be called when the response has been sent.

Then instead of calling the controller's service method explicitly, we send the request through the router so that it can be handled naturally.

Finally, the assertions are set inside the event listener and validate the response body against the expected object.

Using this recipe, you can verify both happy / sad paths on a routing and implementation level.